# Why can't I build up factor from its base data container?

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the internal representation of data containers in `R`. So I tried the following:

Matrix as a Vector with attribute "dim":

```
matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=2)
```

is equivalent to

```
temp <- 1:6
attr(temp,'dim') <- c(3,2)
temp
```

DataFrame as a List with attributes "names", "class" and "row.names":

```
data.frame(
    integerCol=1:9,
    characterCol=sample(c('safe','risky','unsafe'),9,replace=TRUE),
    logicalCol=sample(c(T,F),9,replace=TRUE)
)
```

is equivalent to

```
list(
    integerCol=1:9,
    characterCol=sample(c('safe','risky','unsafe'),9,replace=TRUE),
    logicalCol=sample(c(T,F),9,replace=TRUE)
) -> temp
attr(temp,'class') <- 'data.frame'
attr(temp,'row.names') <- 1:9
temp
```

Factor as a Vector with attributes "levels" and "class":

```
factor(c('risky','safe','risky','unsafe','safe'))
```

should be equivalent to the following:

```
temp <- c(1,2,1,3,2)
attr(temp,'levels') <- c('risky','safe','unsafe')
attr(temp,'class') <- 'factor'
temp
```

But this fails. Why can't I build up a factor here?

Also is there a way to avoid creating a temporary variable `temp` in the above examples? i.e. if there is some way to feed the base attributes to the data structures at the time of creation like `c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 'dim'=c(3,2))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `factor`, it would be `labels`

```
factor(temp, labels = c('risky','safe','unsafe'))
#[1] risky  safe   risky  unsafe safe  
#Levels: risky safe unsafe
```

Or use the `structure`

```
structure(temp, .Label = c('risky','safe','unsafe'), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Thank you `structure(temp, levels = c('risky','safe','unsafe'), class = 'factor')` also works. Its weird that assigning the attributes for factor using `attr` is not working. From now onward, I will just use `structure` for assigning attributes.